# How to avoid insert duplicate record in SQL Server using windows form in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to ask while inserting the data in customer datatable, the customer id, contact no email should be not same. It should show a message box the the particular record is already present in the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS100;Database=CD_Gallery;Integrated Security=true";
        con.Open();

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer_Info values('" + Custid.Text.ToString() + "','" + fname.Text.ToString() + "','" + lname.Text.ToString() + "','" + landmark.Text.ToString() + "','" + address.Text.ToString() + "','" + contact.Text.ToString() + "','" + email.Text.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "','" + deposite.Text.ToString() + "')", con);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (a > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Have Successfully Inserted");
                this.customer_InfoTableAdapter1.Fill(this.cD_GalleryDataSet7Cust_add.Customer_Info);
                Custid.Text = "";
                fname.Text = "";
                lname.Text = "";
                address.Text = "";
                contact.Text = "";
                email.Text = "";
                landmark.Text = "";
                deposite.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Please edit the code, so I could know.......

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Improve the old one..

Comment: Always parameterize your SQL queries.  What happens when someone lives at "123 O'Donnell St." and your INSERT statement breaks?  Also, this is how SQL Injection vulnerabilities are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** **if you want to check for only Duplicate CustomerID(one column)** actually you don't need to write any logic for this , you just need to declare your `Custid` column as `IDENTITY` to solve the issue.

`IDENTITY` columns need not be inserted from `INSERT INTO` statement they will be inserted by default.

**Example:** if you want to start the `Custid` with number 500 and increment for each insertion.

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustID int IDENTITY(500,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

You can skip the values for the `IDENTITY` while writing the `INSERT INTO` statement.

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO Customer(LastName,FirstName,Address,City) 
              VALUES('xyz','abc','address','city');
```

**Solution 2 :** You can write small function to detect wether the customerID is already there in database or not.

Try This:

```
bool CheckDuplicateCustomer(int custid,string contact,string email)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS100;Database=CD_Gallery;Integrated Security=true";
    con.Open();
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Customer_Info where custid = @custid and contactno=@contactno and email=@email", con);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custid",custid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno",contact);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
    int CustomerCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    con.Close();
    if(CustomerCount > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You can call the above function to identify the duplicate customer

call the above function as below from your code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int custid=Convert.ToInt32(CustID.Text);
   int contact=Contact.Text;
   int email=Email.Text;
   if(CheckDuplicateCustomer(custid,contact,email))
   {
         MessageBox.Show("Customer Already Exists with ID "+CustId.Text);
   }
   else
   {

     //your code to insert the customer into table

   } 
}
```

Comment: In question requirement is for uniqueness of combination of columns ie : customer id,contact no email. so declaring customer_id only as identity won't resolve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNIQUE` constraints to make sure that no duplicate values are entered in specific columns that do not participate in a primary key.
As you have table definition already in your database you can add a unique constraint as:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customer_Info
ADD CONSTRAINT uccustomerinfo UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (customer_id,contact_no, email);
```

Check Demo [here](http://rextester.com/DDOIX29491)

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the query to insert the data in the customer datatable, Run another query to see if this record already exists in the table. As you have not mentioned the mata-data of this table, so i am writing an example query assuming some attributes names myself.
Try running this query before the insert query, and if this query returns some values in result set, that means this data already exists in the table, so tell user accordingly, otherwise if it returns NULL, then you can insert the data in the table as this doesn't already exists.

```
"select * from Customer_Info where cust_id = '" +Custid.Text.ToString()+"' OR contact = '" +contact.Text.ToString()+ "' OR email = '"+email.Text.ToString()+"'" ;
```

Comment: by this method there will be two hits to database.. one to check if record exists and in case no then another one for insert.. it will impact performance of code if this function is called frequently during peak traffic loads.

Comment: true that, but as for as Custid is concerned, we can do it as it is identity, and DB manager will handle this, but in case of email and contact, this method might be the only one to use. And btw when we use Custid as an identity and leave it for the DB manager to handle, DB Manager does the same to see the existence of duplicate data. but that is for sure efficient than the one we do ourselves, because DB Manager implemented thing is the done using the best possible algorithms :)

Comment: can u plz edit the code and show how it will work??

Comment: if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from Customer_Info where cust_id = '" +Custid.Text.ToString()+"' OR contact = '" +contact.Text.ToString()+ "' OR email = '"+email.Text.ToString()+"'", con);

/*Now get this cmd executed, and see if it returns some result or not, if it returns some row from database table, that means data that user is trying to enter is duplicate,so in the next if condition, tell user about the duplication, or if result is null,then execute your insert query as you were doing before.*/
/*do it before this bracket*/
}